# Implementing an linked list [C++] compilation error

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, linked-list

### I have the following code:

```
template <class T> 
class List {
    public:
        class Iterator;
        class ConstIterator;

        //Constructors and Destructors.
        List() : head(NULL), tail(NULL), size(0) {}
        List(const List& list);
        ~List();

        //Methods
        Iterator begin();
        Iterator end();
        void insert(const T& data);
        void insert(const T& data, const Iterator& iterator);
        void remove(const Iterator& iterator);
        int getSize() const;
        Iterator find();
        void sort();

        //Operators
        List operator = (const List& list);


    private:
        class Node;
        Node* head;
        Node* tail;
        int size;
};


template <class T>
class List<T>::Node
{
    public:
        //Constructors and destructors
        Node(const T& _data, const Node* _next) : data(_data), next(_next) {}       
        ~Node(); //Destructor 

        //Methods


        //Operators
        Node operator = (const Node& node);

    private:
        T data;
        Node* next;
};


template<class T> 
class List<T>::Iterator 
{
    public:
        Iterator() : list(NULL), node(NULL){} //Constructor
        Iterator(const Iterator& it) : list(it.list), node(it.node) {}
        ~Iterator(); //Destructor

        Iterator& operator=(const Iterator& it); 
        T& operator * ();
        T& operator ++ ();
        T operator ++ (int);
        T& operator -- ();
        T operator -- (int);
        bool operator == (const Iterator& iterator) const;
        bool operator != (const Iterator& iterator) const;


    private:
        List<T>* list;
        Node* node;
};


template<class T> 
class List<T>::ConstIterator 
{
    public:
        ConstIterator() : list(NULL), node(NULL){}
        ConstIterator(const ConstIterator& it) : list(it.list), node(it.node) {}
        ~ConstIterator(); //Destructor

        ConstIterator& operator=(const ConstIterator& it); 
        T& operator * ();
        T& operator ++ ();
        T operator ++ (int);
        T& operator -- ();
        T operator -- (int);
        bool operator == (const ConstIterator& iterator) const;
        bool operator != (const ConstIterator& iterator) const;


    private:
        const List<T>* list;
        const Node* node;
};

template<class T>
Iterator List<T>::begin() {
    return Iterator(this, head);
}
```

---

When I try to compile I get the following error:

```
error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘List’
```

On line:

```
Iterator List<T>::begin() {
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: I got a different error at this line (`g++` 4.8.1). You need to qualify the name `Iterator`: `typename List<T>::Iterator List<T>::begin() {`. Or, `auto List<T>::begin() -> Iterator {`, because then you are "in" `List` so it knows where to look for the name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Iterator` is not defined, but `List<T>::Iterator` is. You will also need to add `typename`:

```
template<class T>
typename List<T>::Iterator List<T>::begin() { ... };
```

Here, `typename` is required as an ambiguitator to tell the compiler that `List<T>::Iterator` is a type (rather than a static member). This is always required in the templated context (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245)).

Comment: Indeed this works but I'm not sure I understand why I should use typename?

Answer (score 0):

if you write the body of the function outside the class declaration, it should be:

`typename List<T>::Iterator List<T>::begin() { ... }`

edit: typename added

Comment: `typename`. It's a dependent type.